# How can I implement C's Structs in Java?

Tags: java, struct

I have a little code that let me register an student (ID, name, age, etc), right now I could do it but just accepting one user, would overwrite if I register a new one, which is what I need now, be able to have more than 1 student.

So I was thinking that if I were using C I would use structs, something like this

```
struct Students {
  int   ID[6];
  char  Name[35];
  char  Age[2];
} student;
```

After reading a bit, Java doesn't have this facility.

How to do this in Java ? Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't a class work?

Comment: A class of students ;)

Comment: What do you mean that Java does not have this facility? What facility?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question itself and the answers to it are specific to to the assignment being solved and unlikely to be of any help to anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has no `struct`.

You can use `class` as structs with members having public access specifier and no methods

Answer (score 2):

In Java you could make a class for students. Once you get to know java better you should change those properties to either private or protected and use public getter/setter methods.

```
public class Student{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

And then in your main code you could create however many students you need:

```
Student myStudentA = new Student();
```

Comment: Do I need to create an object for each student? Can't it be dynamic ?

Comment: What do you mean, "dynamic"?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that in C you would use structs to embody the information you need for each student.

In object-oriented languages like Java, you would use classes. So the equivalent to the C structure you defined would be something like the following class in Java:

```
public class Student
{
    public int         id;         // [*]
    public String      name;
    public String      age;

    //... other things go here, such as constructors and methods ...
}
```

[*] You defined the `id` member to be an array of 6 integers. I assume that you probably meant it to be a single integer value that could hold up to 6 digits.

You probably also want to define the `age` member to be a integer instead of a two-character string.

Note that in Java, `String` variables do not have a maximum length like null-terminated C character arrays do.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I have. 
But do I need to create an Object for each student? Like this: myStudentA = new Student(); and then myStudentB = new Student(); ?

Comment: @DavidSélemGarcia - Yes, each student is embodied within its own `Student` object.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible to do this in Java. Java is an object oriented programming language so when you are dealing with "things", such as students, it is very easy to implement them into a Java class.

Here is one of many ways you could do this:

```
    public class Students{
        private List<Student> students;

        public Students(){
            this.students = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void addStudent(Student newStudent){
            students.add(newStudent);
        }

        public Student getStudents(){
            return this.students;
        }

        public Student getStudent(int name){
            for(Student s : students){
                if(s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                    return student();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public class Student{
            private int id;
            private String name;
            private int age;

            public Student(){

            }

            public Student(int id, String name, int age){
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
                this.age = age;
            }

            // Getters and Setters for the Students variables
        }
    }
```